# File.Delete cannot delete a file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, delete-file, overwrite

I'm getting error when I'm overwriting the file. And if it is still working can't find to way for close file. Can someone help me please ?

```
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/html/" + htmlname)))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("/html/" + htmlname));

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("/html/" + htmlname), mailbody);

        }
        else
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("/html/" + htmlname), mailbody);
        }
```

Comment: In my experience the static File IO methods aren't good about disposing of file handles. I would change to using FileStream and managing the resources yourself; you may be stepping on your own foot.

Comment: @Jeff would you/we implement file writing better or different than what WriteAllText() does?

Comment: @Seration you should first find all places you write to that file. Did you miss a Close()/Dispose()? Is there something asynchronous? Without more context you'll just receive 10.000 suggestions (and if you check them all you _may_ even pick right one...)

Comment: @Adriano The problem is when i write "file." there is no close() or dispose() option. So i really ve no idea about missing someting

Comment: If you write using that static methods you don't need to close it (they do it). You have to close it when you have a stream (for example from File.Open). You have check if you use it in an asynchronous manner too (for example you write and read in different threads or multiple requests). These are just (few) general cases but it's hard to pick right one without more information (what's that file? where do you write it? where do you read it? is it shared by something else?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: Replace all your code with a single call to WriteAllText. It overwrites.

Comment: @Adriano I ve order page. When i click the button save and send mail. This code create the file and save. After that if return the order page to edit and save new file and mail, it s okey too. It s ovewrite. But when i try to second edit. It s booom!

Comment: @usr Sorry i didnt understand your advice. Could you send me example please ?

Comment: Delete everything except one call to WriteAllText.

Comment: @Adriano It's not about better; those methods don't dispose the handle resources upon completion. Your comment that they will close the file handle is misleading as the file will be closed eventually but it happens non-deterministically when the GC decides to dispose.

Comment: @usr it didnt work :/

Comment: That wasn't supposed to fix the problem. It was a comment unrelated to your issue. Your issue is that you have opened the file in question and not closed it. All instances of this error message are the same to resolve: Find, where you did not close the file, or find the other application that is holding it open. We cannot help you do that because we don't know all the places you access the file.

Comment: @Adriano So isnt there anyway close the file using ? Or what should i do ?

Comment: @Seration you cannot force the file to be closed because the code that opened it relies on it staying open. File handle management is cooperative. You can't pull out resources under the feet of other parts of your app. Find, where you did not close this file. Fix the root cause and not the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from msdn.com which is saying that :
"The specified file is in use.
-or-
There is an open handle on the file, and the operating system is Windows XP or earlier. This open handle can result from enumerating directories and files. For more information, see How to: Enumerate Directories and Files."

take a look a this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx

Also doing some search on your own will prove to be efficient on the long run.

Best regards.

Comment: You may be right but it's somehow a big guess (especially assuming he's using XP in production server or for developing).

Comment: I dont really think that when using File.Delete and the exception is IOException its a "guess". Chances are that he tested the code and there is an open handle(or he is viewing it with notepad) and there is that annoying handle.

Comment: It's a guess that handle comes from an enumeration and OS is Windows XP. If you remove that then you simply say "hey your file is in use somewhere, search where you use it". Pretty little for an answer...

Comment: This answer is the best that can be answered given that we don't have more information. There just is an open handle somewhere. He must find it. End of story.